# How can I search with multiple textboxes and only one search button

Tags: vb.net, search

I´m working on an Access database connection with visualstudio visual basic, I have a table with FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, (up to 50 fields). I can´t figure out how to search the table for rows containing the wanted fields. Using textboxes for several fields, and using one search button.

For example, search the table for a product with serialnumber 1 type electronic, name TV.

I can look for one field with the following code:

```
Dim DA As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 LIKE '" & TBField1.Text & "%'", conexion)
Dim DS As New DataSet
DA.Fill(DS, "Table1")
DGV1.DataSource = DSC.Tables("TPruebaB")
```

Tried using this to search 2 fields:

```
Dim DA As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 LIKE '" & TBField1.Text & "%'", conexion)
Dim DS As New DataSet
Dim DA2 As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field2 LIKE '" & TBField2.Text & "%'", conexion)
Dim DS2 As New DataSet

DA.Fill(DS, "Table1")
DA2.Fill(DS2, "Table1")
DGV1.DataSource = DS.Tables("Table1")
```

If i have

```
a----b  
a----c  
b----a   
b----c
```

This works when you search "a" as field 1 and "b" as field 2, but this doesn't work when you search "b" as field 1 and "a" as field 2.

I´m new working with databases and visual basic, I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: So you have 50 text boxes and only some of them will be part of the Where clause. Yes?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but I dont know how to write it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim AndNeeded As Boolean = False
    Dim QueryString = "Select * FROM Table1 WHERE "
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
            If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
                If AndNeeded Then
                    QueryString &= "And "
                End If
                QueryString &= "Field1 Like @Field1 "
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Field1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text & "%"
                AndNeeded = True
            End If
            If TextBox2.Text <> "" Then
                If AndNeeded Then
                    QueryString &= "And "
                End If
                QueryString &= "Field2 Like @Field2 "
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Field2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text & "%"
                AndNeeded = True
            End If
            'And so on for your 50 text boxes
            QueryString = QueryString.Trim & ";"
            Debug.Print(QueryString) 'just to see what the query looks like
            cmd.CommandText = QueryString
            cmd.Connection = cn
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

This code will search for criteria provided in the filled in text boxes. It does not assume that the text boxes that are not filled in must have null data in the associated fields in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just use all the `TextBoxes` all the time and write the query to ignore the empty ones.  Here's an example using two `TextBoxes`:

```
Dim sql = "SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE (@Column1A = '' OR Column1 LIKE '%' + @Column1B + '%')
AND (@Column2A = '' OR Column2 LIKE '%' @Column2B + '%')"
Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@Column1A", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
    .Add("@Column1B", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
    .Add("@Column2A", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox2.Text
    .Add("@Column2B", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox2.Text
End With
```

Unfortunately, because Access only supports positional parameters, you have to add two parameters per `TextBox`.  For SQL Server, the equivalent code would look like this:

```
Dim sql = "SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE (@Column1 = '' OR Column1 LIKE '%' @Column1 + '%')
AND (@Column2 = '' OR Column2 LIKE '%' @Column2 + '%')"
Dim command As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@Column1", SqlType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
    .Add("@Column2", SqlType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox2.Text
End With
```

What that does is match every row to a particular parameter when a `TextBox` is empty and thus that criterion is effectively ignored.  It makes your SQL fairly long but it means that you don't have lots of conditional code in your VB to build the SQL.

EDIT: In my original examples, I was using `=` operators.  I changed them to `LIKE` operators and added wildcards to more closely match your original code and was then about to launch into an explanation of the use of two parameters and realised that you don't actually need two parameters when filtering by text fields using `LIKE`.  That's because an empty string with two wildcards is going to match any value anyway.  That means that, if you are just searching by text fields using `LIKE`, this question isn't actually the one I thought I was answering and it simply comes down to the use of the `AND` operator, as all such Boolean logic does.

```
Dim sql = "SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE Column1 LIKE '%' + @Column1 + '%'
AND Column2 LIKE '%' @Column2 + '%'"
Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@Column1", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
    .Add("@Column2", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox2.Text
End With
```

If you are not using `LIKE` with your text columns or you are using columns with other data types, the more correct way would be to use NULL rather than an empty string.

```
Dim sql = "SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE (@NumberColumnA IS NULL OR NumberColumn = @NumberColumnB)
AND (@TextColumnA IS NULL OR TextColumn = @TextColumnB)"
Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@NumberColumnA", OleDbType.Integer).Value = If(TextBox1.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), CInt(TextBox1.Text))
    .Add("@NumberColumnB", OleDbType.Integer).Value = If(TextBox1.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), CInt(TextBox1.Text))
    .Add("@TextColumnA", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = If(TextBox2.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), TextBox2.Text)
    .Add("@TextColumnB", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = If(TextBox2.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), TextBox2.Text)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I dont get what are Column1A and Column1B

Comment: You would normally name a parameter after the column it is for.  In the second example, a parameter used to filter by `Column1` is named `@Column1` and a parameter for `Column2` is named `@Column2`.  As I said in the answer, Access doesn't allow you to use the same parameter multiple times in the SQL code so, if you want to use the same value twice then you have to add two parameters.  The two parameters being used to filter by `Column1` are `@Column1A` and `@Column1B`.  Etc.